# What does Camel Splitter actually do with XML Document when splitting with xpath?

Tags: xpath, apache-camel

I have a document with an order and a number of lines. I need to break the order into lines so I have a camel splitter set to xpath with the order line as it's value. This works fine.

However, what I get going forward is an element for the order line, which is what I want, but when converting it I need information from the order element - but if I try to get the parent element via xpath following the split, this doesn't work.

Does Camel create copies of the nodes returned by the xpath expression, or return a list of nodes within the parent document? If the former, can I make it the latter? If the latter, any ideas why a "../*" expression would return nothing?

Thanks!

Screwtape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the split options that are available when using a Tokenizer:
http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html

You have four different modes (i, w, u, t) and the 'w' one is keeping the ancestor context. In such case, the parent node (=the thing you apparently need) will be repeated in each sub-message

**Default:**

```
<m:order><id>123</id><date>2014-02-25</date></m:order>
```

**'w' mode:**

```
<m:orders>
  <m:order><id>123</id><date>2014-02-25</date>...</m:order>
</m:orders>
```