# How to partially split an xml in Apache Camel

Tags: xml, apache-camel

I am trying to split this kind of xml with Apache Camel.

input xml

```
<root> 
  <header> 
    <...> 
  </header> 
  <body> 
    <data> one </data>
    <data> two </data>
  </body> 
</root>
```

output xml

```
<root> 
  <header> 
    <...> 
  </header> 
  <body> 
    <data> one </data>  
  </body> 
</root>
```

and

```
<root> 
  <header> 
    <...> 
  </header> 
  <body> 
    <data> two </data>
  </body> 
</root>
```

I have been searching around and could not find an example for that. Is it possible to use only Camel splitter pattern? Or I have to apply some xslt transformation first?

Comment: The answer to my question should give you what you need to use the stax tokeniser splitting on your data element... https://stackoverflow.com/a/51445824/2198651

Comment: @Screwtape I don't know if you could add this as an answer but I upvoted it. Camel makes it so easy :)

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to Screwtape. I found this will work for the example in the question. Bascially 'w' mode will keep all parent/grandparent context.
http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html#Splitter-StreamingbigXMLpayloadsusingTokenizerlanguage

```
Namespaces ns = new Namespaces("ns1", ""); 

from("direct:a")
.split().xtokenize("//ns1:root/body/data", 'w', ns)
.streaming()
.to("direct:b")
```

And for unit test (extends CamelTestSupport),

```
MockEndpoint mockend;  // needs some setup by overriding the createRouteBuilder() method.

mockend.getExchanges().get(0).getIn().getBody().toString()
```

will get you one of the outputs in the question, while get(1) the other.